# How to find CompilationReferences on.NET Core

Tags: c#, roslyn, asp.net-core-1.0

In previous versions of .NET CORE (DNX) you used to be able to find get Roslyn compilation references via something like the following:

```
private static IEnumerable<CompilationReference> GetCompilationReferences(
            ILibraryExporter libraryExporter,
            ApplicationEnvironment environment)
    {
        var export = libraryExporter.GetAllExports(environment.ApplicationName);

        return export.MetadataReferences
                 .OfType<IRoslynMetadataReference>()
                 .OrderBy(reference => reference.Name)
                 .Select(reference =>  reference.MetadataReference as CompilationReference);
    }
```

In the latest .NET Core runtime the IRoslynMetadataReference is no longer supported, therefore not sure how to get the equivalent under the new runtime (Currently running runtime 1.0.0-2702). Refer to https://github.com/dotnet/cli

In the latest version I have managed to get access to the LibraryExporter via the following code

```
var appInfo = new ApplicationInfo("TestApp", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
var runtime = RuntimeEnvironmentExtensions.GetRuntimeIdentifier(PlatformServices.Default.Runtime);
var projectContext = ProjectContext.CreateContextForEachFramework(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), null, new[] { runtime }).First();
var libaryExporter = new LibraryExporter(projectContext, appInfo);

var exports = libaryExporter.GetAllExports();
var metaDataRefs = exports.SelectMany(x => x.GetMetadataReferences()).ToList();
```

This gives me the list of MetadataReference types however when casting these as a CompilationReference this returns null.

The reason for attempting to get compilation references out is part of a self building documentation for our code set. The compilation references are used to get the SyntaxTrees and look for summary comments on classes/properties which are then used to produce a help API for the solution.

If anyone has tried doing this sort of thing on the new platform or even has an alternate approach to getting the comments out this would be appreciated.